# have text before or on image depending on screen size

Tags: html, css

**My Goal:**
I want that on small screen the red box appear's before the image and on large screen the red box should appear on the image:
[image]

The following snippet almost works, however, the text is placed below the image and not before the image on small screen size

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper>img {
  width: 700px;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  max-height: 459px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.point {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 4.92%;
  margin-top: -8.02%;
  z-index: 15;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .content {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: -15%;
    position: absolute;
  }
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 15;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://www.edrawsoft.com/templates/images/city-street-map.png"></img>
  <a class="point">
  </a>
  <p class="content">
    Here is very important info about point
  </p>
</div>
```

**Outcome of my snippet:**

[image]

**Changing html order:**

When I place the `<p>` tag before the image like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="content">
    Here is very important info about point
  </p>      
  <img src="https://www.edrawsoft.com/templates/images/city-street-map.png"></img>
  <a class="point">
  </a>
</div>
```

Then the box appears before the image on small screen-size, but on large screen size its now shown at all, although I use z-index:

[image]

Why is the last approach not working? Or how can I get a solution that covers both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS grid to fix this:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.wrapper > img {
  width: 700px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 459px;
}

.point {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 4.92%;
  bottom: 8.02%;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: -15%;
  position: absolute;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: inline-grid;
  }
  .content {
    order:-1;
    position: static;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://www.edrawsoft.com/templates/images/city-street-map.png">
  <a class="point">
  </a>
  <p class="content">
    Here is very important info about point
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write few CSS in media query for lower resolution then 600px.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

Updated the above changes in below code snippet, I hope it'll help you out. Thank You

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper>img {
  width: 700px;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  max-height: 459px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.point {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 4.92%;
  margin-top: -8.02%;
  z-index: 15;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .content {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: -15%;
    position: absolute;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    padding-top: 48px;
  }
  .content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 15;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://www.edrawsoft.com/templates/images/city-street-map.png"></img>
  <a class="point">
  </a>
  <p class="content">
    Here is very important info about point
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, but now the message box is not before the image, its on top of the image (meaning there is overlap). Is it possible to put it before the image without overlap?

Comment: Mentioned changes updated on above code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Top" and "Left" instead of margin-left and margin-top. Also add absolute position to your default content class:

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .content {
     left: 10%;
     top: -15%;
     position: absolute;
  }
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 15;
  position: absolute;
}
```